# Create multiple folders to save several sessions on mobaXterm

Tags: session, directory

I depend heavily on MobaXterm to connect to remote servers. My saved session list is beyond manageable now. Is there a way to create folders and organize my sessions in MobaXterm?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think yes, you can do that, have a look: https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html,

Answer (score 3):

Sure: Right click on User sessions:

[image]

And then "new folder"

[image]